# При скачивании картинки программа не видит ее, но при перезапуске все работает, Java

Tags: java, javafx, исключения, изображения

В программе скачиваю картинку, проверяю папку, там она имеется. Пытаюсь ее отрисовать, выбрасывает `java.lang.NullPointerException`.
Перезапускаю прогу, картинка не скачивается, так как имеется проверка на ее существование. Пытаюсь отрисовать - все работает.

Делает ли java грубо говоря "скриншот" системы при запуске, а потом не реагирует на новые файлы? Если да, то как исправить?

```
//сначала происходит загрузка с сайта
private void getPictureFromWeatherSite(Forecast forecast){ 
    String fileName = "C:\\Users\\alexandr\\Desktop\\Java\\weather\\src\\main\\java\\pictures\\" +
            forecast.returnUrlForecastImage().
                    substring(forecast.returnUrlForecastImage().lastIndexOf("/"));
    if (!(new File(fileName)).exists()) {
            new Downloader("http:"+ forecast.returnUrlForecastImage(), fileName);
    }
}
//затем создание объекта на основе скачанной картинки
weatherTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellRenderer(
            new ImageRenderer(data, "pictures" + forecast.returnUrlForecastImage().
                    substring(forecast.returnUrlForecastImage().lastIndexOf("/"))));
```

А вот класс, который занимается отрисовкой

```
class ImageRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

private JLabel lbl = new JLabel();
private Object[][] data;
private String picture;

ImageRenderer(Object[][] data, String picture){
    this.picture = picture;
    this.data = data;
}

public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected,
                                               boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
    if(row == 1) {
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(picture));
        lbl.setText("");
        lbl.setIcon(icon);
    }
    else {
        lbl.setText((String) data[row][column]);
        lbl.setIcon(null);
    }
    return lbl;
}
} 
// код изменения картинки (model - DefaultTableModel)
public void changeData(String date){
    for(int i=3; i>=0; i--)
        model.removeRow(i);
    setData(date);
    for(int i=0; i<data.length; i++){
        model.insertRow(i, data[i]);
    }
    weatherTable.setModel(model);
    Forecast forecast = getCurrentForecast(sinoptik.returnForecasts(), date);
    weatherTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellRenderer(
            new ImageRenderer(data, "pictures" + forecast.returnUrlForecastImage().
                    substring(forecast.returnUrlForecastImage().lastIndexOf("/"))));
    forecast = getCurrentForecast(gismeteo.returnForecasts(), date);
    weatherTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setCellRenderer(
            new ImageRenderer(data, "pictures" + forecast.returnUrlForecastImage().
                    substring(forecast.returnUrlForecastImage().lastIndexOf("/"))));
}
```

Comment: Добавьте код скачивания и отрисовки,а так же сообщение об ошибке

Comment: Как тебе это поможет? Я упоминал, что при повторном запуске программы все работает. Ошибка кроется в том, что компилятор не видит скачанный файл.

Comment: Компилятор не видит скачанный файл? ;) Похоже, что ваша программа создаёт какой-то объект, в котором должна быть картинка. На момент запуска программы этой картинки нет, и во время работы состояние объекта не обновляется, поэтому NPE. После перезапуска картинка есть, поэтому всё нормально. Код в студию.

Comment: Да, ты полностью прав! Код подгрузил, подскажи, пожалуйста, как решить проблему.

Comment: ImageRenderer создаётся перед каждой отрисовкой или при запуске программы? При создании этого объекта в конструкторе жёстко задаётся String picture, на основе которого потом подгружается изображение ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(picture));

Comment: Создается перед каждой отрисовкой картинки. Да, все верно. Что делать?)

Comment: Вы уверены, что "//сначала происходит загрузка с сайта" и "//затем создание объекта на основе скачанной картинки" обрабатываются последовательно?

Comment: На все 100%. Я вижу, что картинка уже в папке, а потом нажимаю на кнопку для ее отрисовки, но происходит ошибка.

Comment: Что делать? :((

Comment: Код нажатия на кнопку выложите.

Comment: Готово, спасайте))0)

Comment: Есть какие-нибудь идеи?

Comment: в приведенном коде нет ожидания завершения скачивания. Покажите код `Dowloader` класса и связанные с ним слушатели. Если таковых нет, то причина в этом: инициализация отображения происходит до того как картинка скачалась.

Comment: Нет, я вижу скачанную картинку в папке, а после этого создаю объект. Это 100% проверенная информация.

Comment: Текущего кода недостаточно что бы решить проблему. Гадать что и как у вас там происходит, тоже не охота) Выложите куда-нибудь полный код, или вырезку на которой воспроизводится проблема. После этого смогу помочь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот простой пример: по нажатию на кнопку сохраняет изображение на жесткий диск, загружает изображение с жесткого диска, отображает его в таблице.

Для теста с исходными данными создайте папку `temp` на диске `С`.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TableColumn<MyImageObject, Image> imageTableColumn = new TableColumn<>("Image");
        imageTableColumn.setCellValueFactory(param -> param.getValue().image);
        imageTableColumn.setCellFactory(param -> new ImageCell());

        TableColumn<MyImageObject, String> urlTableColumn = new TableColumn<>("URL");
        urlTableColumn.setCellValueFactory(param -> param.getValue().url);

        TableColumn<MyImageObject, String> filePathTableColumn = new TableColumn<>("File path");
        filePathTableColumn.setCellValueFactory(param -> param.getValue().filePath);

        final TableView<MyImageObject> tableView = new TableView<>();
        tableView.getColumns().addAll(imageTableColumn, urlTableColumn, filePathTableColumn);

        // поле для указания url исходного изображения
        final TextField urlTextField = new TextField("https://hsto.org/web/c90/c58/4ad/c90c584ad04e44249bb11d97461ee0e3.png");
        // путь до файла, в который это изображение надо будет сохранить
        // для теста не забудь создать папку temp на диске С
        final TextField filePathTextField = new TextField("/temp/example.png");

        Button addItemButton = new Button("Add item");
        addItemButton.setOnAction(event -> {
            try {
                tableView.getItems().add(loadMyImageObject(urlTextField.getText(), filePathTextField.getText()));
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                throw new RuntimeException(ex.getMessage(), ex);
            }
        });

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(new BorderPane(tableView,
                new HBox(10, new Text("URL:"), urlTextField, new Text("File path:"), filePathTextField, addItemButton),
                null, null, null)));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    // получение нашего произвольного объекта
    static MyImageObject loadMyImageObject(String url, String filePath) throws IOException {
        // сохраняем изображение на жесткий диск
        Path path = saveImage(url, filePath);
        // загружаем изображение из файла на жестком диске
        Image image = new Image(new FileInputStream(path.toFile()));

        MyImageObject myImageObject = new MyImageObject();
        myImageObject.url = new SimpleStringProperty(url);
        myImageObject.filePath = new SimpleStringProperty(filePath);
        myImageObject.image = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(image);
        return myImageObject;
    }

    // сохранение изображения из url в файл
    static Path saveImage(String url, String filePath) throws IOException  {
        Path path;
        try(InputStream in = new URL(url).openStream()){
            Files.copy(in, path = Paths.get(filePath));
        }
        return path;
    }

    // простой объект для хранения данных и дальнейшего отображения
    static class MyImageObject {
        ObjectProperty<Image> image;
        StringProperty url, filePath;
    }

    // ячейка таблицы, отображающая изображения
    static class ImageCell extends TableCell<MyImageObject, Image> {

        private ImageView imageView;

        public ImageCell() {
            setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
        }

        @Override
        protected void updateItem(Image item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            if (empty || item == null) {
                setGraphic(null);
            } else {
                if (imageView == null) {
                    imageView = new ImageView();
                }
                imageView.setImage(item);
                setGraphic(imageView);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Все работает, спасибо большое за помощь!

Comment: На этом форуме принято помечать ответ как верный, если он решил вопрос. Придерживайтесь этики форума.

Comment: Спасибо, но я уже отметил вчера. "Оценки участников с репутацией меньше 15 не показываются".

Comment: @VasyaPupkin Слева от ответа поищите серую галку. Нажмите на нее, чтобы отметить ответ как правильный. Почитайте: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers